# How can I wire this dimmer switch?

Tags: electrical

I'm trying to put a light and a dimmer switch together for use in a chicken brooder. I have the switch and porcelain light socket but am a bit confused on the wiring diagram. My diagram looks exactly like the one found here

[image]

Basically I have a cord with a plug on one end and want to cut it in half, put both ends into opposite sides of a surface mount electrical box and have one side go to the wall (plug end) and the other go to the light fixture. From that diagram I only see two wires coming in from outside the switch but I'll have 4, not counting the ground wires which I also want to use and don't know where to put. Additionally, there are two wires coming from the dimmer mechanism but they show clearly going to 'loop' and 'c'.
So if someone could fill in the blanks below I'd be grateful!

Plug-brown?    (Loop, C, 1, or 2)

Plug- blue? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)

Plug-ground? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)

Light-brown? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)

Light-blue? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)

Light-ground? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)

Comment: Where in the world are you located & I only see one diagram there, no page 6...

Comment: Can you post a URL to some kind of data sheet or user manual for this dimming assembly?

Answer (score 2):

From the diagram it looks like the dimming assembly is simply in series with the load, on the hot side.

Yes, if you have two conductor cord, and you cut it, then you have four wire ends. The dimmer would be spliced into the hot wire, and the other one would have to be spliced back together.  It would make sense to just cut one conductor in the cord.  Leave one intact. The intact one is your N to Load line, and the one you cut gives you the other two pieces: A to dimmer, dimmer to load.

What to do with ground wires? You have two devices: dimmer and load (light socket). If the dimmer has a metal chassis, you can ground that. Follow manufacturer's instructions!

The light receptacle is porcelain, so don't bother.

Comment: Thanks Kaz but could you just fill in the question marks I have above? I still find your explanation a bit confusing. And the cable has 3 wires, as above.

Comment: Okay, right, so the third wire is ground.

Comment: What does the dashed box represent in your diagram. Is that a ready-made part, or is that just your junction box?

Comment: That is just the outline of the front of the plate. Is it possible to just fill in the ?'s  ?

Comment: <p>
Plug-brown?    (Loop, C, 1, or 2)<p>
Plug- blue? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)<p>
Plug-ground? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)<p>
Light-brown? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)<p>
Light-blue? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)<p>
Light-ground? (Loop, C, 1, or 2)<p>

Comment: I do not understand that. I don't have your cable to see its colors, and your picture is black and white. Use a continuity tester or multimeter to figure out which wire colors go with which prongs of the plug so you know which is hot, neutral and ground.

Comment: Whichever wire connects to the hot prong of the plug would be cut. The plug-side of the cut would be attached to 1, and then the loads-side would attach to the loop terminal, from where it continues to the light.  Whichever wire is neutral can go straight from the plug to the light, without being cut. The ground wire can be used to ground any metal enclosures, as recommended by the accompanying literature for the devices (switch and dimmer). Nothing like that is shown in your diagram. The piece of ground wire going out to the light won't do anything.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thanks for all your time!

Comment: Be careful around that line voltage, Kent!

Comment: Are you still here? Just want to be clear. The dimmer switch itself only has two red wires coming out of the dimmer box. By the diagram I see they go to loop and C. The other wires are only in the cord. I'll take the Blue/black wire and put the plug end of it into 1 on the diagram and then put the light end of it into loop on the diagram. The brown/red wire can stay uncut and the yellow/green ground wire could also stay uncut? as there is no grounding place in the diagram?

Comment: Never-mind. It all works. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Kent Sparks, I hope you will see this. While what you have will work, I fear you have created a dangerous condition. You have cut the dimmer into the neutral side, meaning the light will always be hot no matter the dimmer condition. The dimmer should be cut into the hot side. In all country wiring color schemes, brown is always hot, never neutral. Blue and black can go either way, but blue is a very common neutral color, confirmed by being paired with the always hot brown. You must splice the dimmer into the brown, connect the blue/black back together, leave the yellow/green ground alone.

Comment: Thanks bcworkz. I will make the appropriate change. I just took the guy at the lamp shop for his word when he said blue was hot. But I confirmed your information here [Link] (http://www.accesscomms.com.au/reference/powerplug.htm) which in hindsight I should have done before.  :-)

Comment: See my comment above: *Use a continuity tester or multimeter to figure out which wire colors go with which prongs of the plug so you know which is hot, neutral and ground.* Don't trust the colors: confirm the actual connectivity.